# Get data by array of ids

Tags: javascript, database, sequelize.js, associations, sequelize-cli

I'm trying to make a filter songs for a my project, i have an array of genres ids that i retrieve from the client, i do this for get all the audios from one id:

```
Audio.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: db.Genres,
    as: "genres",
    where: {
      id: {
        [Op.and]: [1]
      }
    },
  }]
})
```

But i need to get all audios from an array of genres/mods ids, also want filter audios by genre ids and mods ids, but i don'y know how to make it, any idea?

**Song Model**

```
const Audio =  sequelize.define('Audio', {
  id: {
    autoIncrement: true,
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER(30),
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
    allowNull: false
  },
})
Audio.associate = function(models) {
  Audio.belongsToMany(models.Genres, {through: 'AudioGenres', foreignKey: 'id_audio', as: 'genres'})
  Audio.belongsToMany(models.Mods, {through: 'AudioMods', foreignKey: 'id_audio', as: 'mods'})
}
```

**AudioGenreModel**

```
const AudioGenres =  sequelize.define('AudioGenres', {
  id_audio: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    references: {
      model: 'Audio',
      key: 'id'
    }
  },
  id_genre: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    references: {
      model: 'Genres',
      key: 'id'
    }
})
AudioGenres.associate = function(models) {
  AudioGenres.belongsTo(models.Audio, {foreignKey: 'id_audio'})
  AudioGenres.belongsTo(models.Genres, {foreignKey: 'id_genre'})
};
```

**AudioModModel**

```
const AudioMods =  sequelize.define('AudioMods', {
  id_audio: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    references: {
      model: 'Audio',
      key: 'id'
    }
  },
  id_mod: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    references: {
      model: 'Mods',
      key: 'id'
    }
})
AudioMods.associate = function(models) {
  AudioMods.belongsTo(models.Audio, {foreignKey: 'id_audio'})
  AudioMods.belongsTo(models.Mods, {foreignKey: 'id_mod'})
};
```

**Mods and Genres Model**

```
const Mods =  sequelize.define('Mods', {
  id: {
    autoIncrement: true,
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER(30),
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
    allowNull: false
  },
})
Mods.associate = function(models) {
  Mods.belongsToMany(models.Audio, {through: 'AudioMods', foreignKey: 'id_mod', as: 'audios'})
}

const Genres =  sequelize.define('Genres', {
  id: {
    autoIncrement: true,
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER(30),
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
    allowNull: false
  },
})
Genres.associate = function(models) {
  Genres.belongsToMany(models.Audio, {through: 'AudioGenres', foreignKey: 'id_genre', as: 'audios'})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Op.in` query operator when finding a column that is in an array of values. Many of the fields in your definition will be automatically created with the relationships, for `AudioGenres` and `AudioMods` you can initially create them with no fields.

```js
// only define name, others will be generated
const Audio =  sequelize.define('Audio', {
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
    allowNull: false
  },
});
Audio.associate = function(models) {
  Audio.belongsToMany(models.Genres, { as: 'genres', through: 'AudioGenres', foreignKey: 'id_audio' })
  Audio.belongsToMany(models.Mods, { as: 'mods', through: 'AudioMods', foreignKey: 'id_audio' })
}

const Genres =  sequelize.define('Genres', {
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
    allowNull: false
  },
});
Genres.associate = function(models) {
  Genres.belongsToMany(models.Audio, { as: 'audios', through: 'AudioGenres', foreignKey: 'id_genre' })
}

const Mods =  sequelize.define('mods', {
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
    allowNull: false
  },
});
Mods.associate = function(models) {
  Mods.belongsToMany(models.Audio, { as: 'audios', through: 'AudioMods', foreignKey: 'id_mod' })
}

// create empty table, relationships added automatically
const AudioGenres = sequelize.define('AudioGenres', {}, { timestamps: false });
const AudioMods = sequelize.define('AudioMods', {}, { timestamps: false });
```

Use the `Op.in` query operator, arrays for table joins.

```js
// use the Sequelize.Op query operators, specifically Op.in
const { Op } = require('sequelize');

// these are the values to use for the joins.
const myArrayOfGenreIds = [1, 2, ...];
const myArrayOfModIds = [1, 2, ...];
```

Query for values in an array joining both tables on the IDs in the arrays and returning results where one of them is not null.

```js
// now query for Audios joined to Genres and Mods through relationship tables
const audios = await Audio.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Genres,
      as: 'genres',
      attributes: [],
      where: {
        id: {
          [Op.in]: myArrayOfGenreIds,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      model: Mods,
      as: 'mods',
      attributes: [],
      where: {
        id: {
          [Op.in]: myArrayOfModIds,
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  // only return results from Audios
  group: [sequelize.col('audios.id')],
  having: {
    // check to see if the count of IDs we got back matches the count we expect
    [Op.and]: [
      sequelize.where(
        sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('genres.id')), 
        myArrayOfGenreIds.length)
      ),
      sequelize.where(
        sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('mods.id')), 
        myArrayOfModIds.length)
      ),
    ],
  },
});
```

Comment: Wow nice, but I need to filter the audios that contain all the genres of the array, any ideas?

Comment: @RicardoAlvarado not sure if I understand, in my example `myArrayOfGenreIds` is an array of genre IDs and `myArrayOfModIds` is an array of mod IDs that you want to filter by. If you want to use a `LEFT JOIN` (making both optional) add `required: false` to the includes.

Comment: This query returns me all the audios that contain at les one id of the array, i need all the audios that contains all the ids of the array. I'm trying this: https://imgur.com/a/q13uQyC

Comment: Ahh, I see. I would probably do this by only joining to the Genres, grouping by the `Audio.id`, then checking the `COUNT(Genre.ID)` in a `HAVING` clause.